# Vagrant slow SSH (Ubuntu trusty host & client) on Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I am having trouble with setting up a Vagrant SSH connection with Virtualbox provider. I am quite new to both Ruby and Vagrant as well. I am wondering if anyone could help me and point in the right direction on how to solve this problem.

I am attaching all the possible information that I think could be useful.

```
root@node1:~/VagrantStuff/vbVagrantSimple# vagrant up
Bringing machine '01-firstVBServer' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Setting the name of the VM: vbVagrantSimple_01-   firstVBServer_1488206801438_77523
==> 01-firstVBServer: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> 01-firstVBServer: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
01-firstVBServer: Adapter 1: nat
01-firstVBServer: Adapter 2: hostonly
01-firstVBServer: Adapter 3: bridged
==> 01-firstVBServer: Forwarding ports...
01-firstVBServer: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> 01-firstVBServer: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Booting VM...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
01-firstVBServer: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
01-firstVBServer: SSH username: vagrant
01-firstVBServer: SSH auth method: private key
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
01-firstVBServer: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Machine booted and ready!
==> 01-firstVBServer: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Setting hostname...
==> 01-firstVBServer: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
```

Total time to "vagrant up": 8min ++ (I stopped the timer here, was already annoyed by how long that took).
Time to get to the SSH attempt: 45 secs (OK time).
Time to get to actually SSH with retrying: 2:05 minutes (NOK)
Time to configure and enable network interfaces : 5 min ++ (NOK).

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

 vagrant_version = Vagrant::VERSION.sub(/^v/, '')

 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
     v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
     v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
     v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
     v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
 end

 config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
 config.ssh.forward_agent = true
 config.ssh.insert_key = false
 config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.4"


 ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'


 config.vm.define "01-firstVBServer", primary: true do |firstVBServer|

   firstVBServer.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
   firstVBServer.vm.hostname = "01-firstServer-VB"
   firstVBServer.vm.network "public_network" , bridge: "eth0"
   firstVBServer.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }

   firstVBServer.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
   end

   firstVBServer.vm.provision :shell, inline: "
    sudo echo \"Acquire::http::Proxy \\\"http://31.250.0.80:8118\\\";\" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
    sudo apt-get -y update
    sudo apt-get -y upgrade"
 end

end
```

I ran the vagrant up in DEBUG mode as well, I do not think it is really helpful, but here is the 21000 lines output, if anyone takes it too seriously:

```
vagrant up
```

in DEBUG mode:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=11702713612886687285

I am thankful for any attempts of helping me.